# What is an algebraic solution to this Math Card Trick?

Tags: functions

Pick a number from the deck (Ace=1, Jack=11, Queen=12, King=13).
-Double the face value of the card (the number)
-Add 1
-Multiply by 5
-If it's a: 
   Club - add 5
   Diamond -add 6
   Heart - add 7
   Spade - add 8

You tell me your answer I tell you your card.

To find someone's card subtract 5 from their answer(ex. 42 - 5 = 37, the tens digit is the face value of the card, the ones digit corresponds with what they added at the end. In this case since its 7 it is a heart, therefore the card was the 3 of hearts.)

Can someone demonstrate this algebraicly to show the progression from the beginning then how subtracting 5 gives you the card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R$ be the rank number (e.g., $R=12$ for a Queen) and $S$ be the suit number.

Then the number $N$ presented is
$$
N = ((2R +1) \cdot 5) + S = 10R + S + 5
$$
If you subtract $5$ you get $10R + S$ which is just $R$ in the tens (and sometimes hundreds) place, and S in the ones place.

Answer (score 1):

Let $r$ be the rank of the card. The calculation first produces $5(2r+1)=10r+5$ and then adds $5,6,7$, or $8$ depending on the suit. If $s$ is the number added for the suit, the final figure is $10r+s+5$. When you subtract $5$, you’re left with $10r+s$. No matter which suit the card is, $s$ is a one-digit number, so it’s the one’s digit of $10r+s$. Erase it, and what’s left is $r$.